# what is the difference between the two openssl commands below

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

what is the difference between the commands below :

command 1:

```
openssl x509 -req -in certs/server_csr.pem -CA certs/intermediate_cert.pem -CAkey private/intermediate_key.pem -out server_cert.pem -CAcreateserial -days 365 -sha256 -extfile server_cert_ext.cnf
```

command 2:

```
openssl ca -config ~/myCA/openssl_intermediate.cnf -extensions server_cert -days 375 -notext -md sha256 -in certs/server_csr.pem -out server_cert.pem
```

Both commands sign csr request and generate a server certificate, but I can't tell what is the difference between them.

Comment: So, you want to know the difference between `x509 -ca` and `ca`?

Comment: @schroeder yes in a way.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the second command uses the entire CA “infrastructure” defined in the CA configuration and consisting of, for example, a certificate database, a counter for the serial numbers, a policy for validating Distinguished Names and a set of default settings (algorithms, key sizes etc.).

The first command is an ad-hoc way of creating a certificate. It does not use any CA configuration (just the key), it does not store the certificate in a database, and it does not use a serial number counter. Instead, the serial number 01 is used (and a new file which may be used as a counter in future commands is created).